# javascript: Building an object inside an object and adding key/value pairs to it

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, key-value

I start out with an empty object in the global scope and then I fetch an ID at a time to which I'd like to add prices together with a quantity.
The script iterates through a list and for each row the ID is present, I wish to add `quantity: price`

I want my object to look something like this:

```
const obj = {
  id1: {
    qty1: price
    qty2: price
    qty3: price
    qty4: price
    qty5: price
    qty6: price
    qty7: price
  }
  id2: {
    qty1: price
    qty2: price
    qty3: price
    qty4: price
    qty5: price
    qty6: price
    qty7: price
  }
}
```

Currently I'm just getting one price as each run replaces the other.

```
const obj = {}
obj[id] = { [qty]: price }

// Result
obj: {
  id: {
    qty: price
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the input you're processing? Is it an array of objects that have an `id` key and a `price` key? Or just an array of integers? Are you doing multiple fetches, getting multiple lists, each corresponding to an id?

Comment: Please provide code with which the problem can be reproduced. Currently your code just defines an object with one property, but that is normal since you only ... define one property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you always can spread

```
const obj = {}
obj[id] = {...obj[id], qty: price }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new object only if there isn't any already

```
if (!obj[id]) obj[id] = {}
if (!obj[id][qty]) obj[id][qty] = {}
```

I've added a loop to show how it works:

```js
const ids = ['id1', 'id2']
const qtys = ['qty1', 'qty2']
const price = 1

const obj = {}

for (const id of ids) {
  for (const qty of qtys) {
    if (!obj[id]) obj[id] = {}
    if (!obj[id][qty]) obj[id][qty] = {}
    obj[id][qty] = Math.random() * 100 | 0
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```